# Any way to DRY up this code? + "toLowerCase()"

Tags: javascript, variables, dry

I am fairly new to JavaScript.
I need two things please:

1. To DRY up my code. To be specific, the ***hasMoreOscarsThan*** method for {**leo**} object has lots of variables declared inside. 
   I need to use those variables again somehow in 4 other methods for the objects {**jenn**}, {**sam**}, {**mery**} and {**john**}.

Declaring those variables as global simply won't work because I don't even want to change their values later.

Any way to DRY up these variables when using them inside other ***hasMoreOscarsThan*** methods for other objects?

2. I have the ***getActorByName()*** function. I couldn't use the ***toLowerCase()*** or ***toUpperCase()*** functions inside it. Why?

As you know, the user mostly will not try to write the name "Leonardo DiCaprio", for example, exactly as it is in capital letters and small letters. ***toLowerCase()*** would solve the problem for me but I couldn't manage to let it work! Why?

Thank you very much in advance!

```js
var actors = [
  leo = {
    name: 'Leonardo DiCaprio',
    age: 41,
    oscars: 1,
    hello: function() {
      var logActorName0 = console.log('Hello, my name is: ' + leo.name);


    // hasMoreOscarsThan - this method accepts one actor object as a parameter and
    //     returns true if the actor has more Oscars than the one that is passed as
    //     a parameter and false otherwise.


    },
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function(actorObj) {
      var leoName = actors[0].name;
      var jennName = actors[1].name;
      var samName = actors[2].name;
      var meryName = actors[3].name;
      var johnName = actors[4].name;
      var leoOscars = actors[0].oscars;
      var jennOscars = actors[1].oscars;
      var samOscars = actors[2].oscars;
      var meryOscars = actors[3].oscars;
      var johnOscars = actors[4].oscars;
      if (actorObj === leoName && leoOscars > leoOscars) {
        return true;
      } else if (actorObj === jennName && leoOscars > jennOscars) {
        return true;
      } else if (actorObj === samName && leoOscars > samOscars) {
        return true;
      } else if (actorObj === meryName && leoOscars > meryOscars) {
        return true;
      } else if (actorObj === johnName && leoOscars > johnOscars) {
        return true;
      } else if (actorObj !== leoName && actorObj !== jennName && actorObj !== samName && actorObj !== meryName && actorObj !== johnName) {
        var falseSearch = "Please enter a valid actor name!";
        return falseSearch;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  jenn = {
    name: 'Jennifer Lawrence',
    age: 25,
    oscars: 1,
    hello: function() {
      var logActorName1 = console.log('Hello, my name is: ' + jenn.name);
    },
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function(actorObj) {
      console.log(leoname);
    }
  },

  sam = {
    name: 'Samuel L. Jackson',
    age: 67,
    oscars: 0,
    hello: function() {
      var logActorName2 = console.log('Hello, my name is: ' + sam.name);
    },
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function(actorObj) {

    }
  },
  mery = {
    name: 'Meryl Streep',
    age: 66,
    oscars: 3,
    hello: function() {
      var logActorName3 = console.log('Hello, my name is: ' + mery.name);
    },
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function(actorObj) {

    }
  },

  john = {
    name: 'John Cho',
    age: 43,
    oscars: 0,
    hello: function() {
      var logActorName4 = console.log('Hello, my name is: ' + john.name);
    },
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function(actorObj) {

    }
  },

  
function getActorByName(actor){
  var leoName = actors[0].name;
  var jennName = actors[1].name;
  var samName = actors[2].name;
  var meryName = actors[3].name;
  var johnName = actors[4].name;
    if (actor === leoName){
      return (leo);
    } else if (actor === jennName){
      return (jenn);
    } else if (actor === samName){
      return (sam);
    } else if (actor === meryName){
      return (mery);
    } else if (actor === johnName){
      return (john);
    } else if (actor !== leoName && actor !== jennName && actor !== samName && actor !== meryName && actor !== johnName){
      return "No Such An Actor Found!";
    }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Actors</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: If the code works, it's off topic here. Please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Have you tried using loops?

Comment: You shouldn’t assign variables in an array (i.e. `[leo = {...}]`). Instead, use an object: `{leo: {...}}` or an array without those names: `[{...}]`. If you do assign variables in an array, you’ll end up assigning global variables, which you probably don’t want.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am sorry but I don't know how to copy it to Code Review. It needs a Moderator I guess?

Comment: @Bergi I did. It didn't work.

Comment: @JF The thing is that this is an assignment I have to do. One of the requirements. I have to create an array of five object. Each object has a name and of course properties and values. Assigning variables as global is not a problem here since it is gonna solve my problem. Nothing more I have to do after doing this.

Comment: @Redu I commented out what "hasMoreOscarsThan" method should have.  I think with your solution, you went far away from the original task I have. I think the solution has to be more simple that the one you gave to me since I am learning Javascript in school and this is my first assignment. The method should only take one parameter which is the actor and compare its oscars with the one who has the method.

Comment: @Adam Can you add that attempt to your question, please? It's the correct approach, so let's find out what went wrong.

Comment: @Bergi Check my answer below. So I need to pass only one actor object as a parameter and compare its oscars to the actor who I am calling his method.
ex: **leo.hasMoreOscarsThan("Samuel L. Jackson")** MUST return true simply because leo has 1 and sam has 0. Same applies to other actors when compared to leo. The loop didn't work because it will return only one actor. 
The only way I could solve this is by declaring all variables inside the method one by one and then simply go for the if statement.
I declared the same variables in each actor **hasMoreOscarsThan** methods. I couldn't DRY it!

Comment: @Bergi `hasMoreOscarsThan: function (actorObj){
      var leoName = actors[0].name;
      var leoOscars = actors[0].oscars;
      for (var i = 0; i < actors.length; i++){
        var actorsNames = actors[i].name;
        var actorsOscars = actors[i].oscars;
        console.log(actorsNames);
        console.log(actorsOscars);
      }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*The loop didn't work because it will return only one actor.*" Instead of logging the names and oscars, check for each name whether it's the actor you're looking for, and then return whether she has more oscars than the other one.

Comment: Btw, you really should consider passing an `actorObj` to the method like the parameter name suggests, instead of passing an actor name. Then make another method who selects an actor (object) from the array by name.

Comment: @Bergi If you tried to return (actorsNames) or return (actorsOscars) inside the loop, you will only get 1 actor name for actorsNames and 1 actor oscar property value for actorsOscars. Checking each name won't work because I have actors[i].names which logs all actors names. That's why if I want to check each actor, I have to not use the loop. I used a forEach() but did not work either.

Comment: @Bergi in the for loop, I cannot pass the actorObj as a parameter because I have to pass only one actor but the loop will let me pass more. This won't work. I have to declare a variable for each actor and each variable has a value of an actor name (that would be five variables) and another 5 variables for each actor have a value of each actor oscar.

Comment: @Bergi Check this link out. This is the final version. I couldn't have a better solution. http://codepen.io/AdamAshour/pen/ALRKLY

Comment: "*Checking each name won't work*" - of course it does! That's exactly what you're going to do with the one name you get in each iteration. `console.log(actorsNames);` does not log all names at once, it logs a single name every time it is called.

Comment: @Bergi Please edit the code at http://codepen.io/AdamAshour/pen/ALRKLY and show me how this gonna return the value I want? Don't forget that the result of the comparison should be a value returned, either true or false. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want is a simple loop:

```
hasMoreOscarsThan: function (actorObj) {
    var myOscars = this.oscars;
    for (var i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
        var actorName = actors[i].name;
        if (actorName == actorObj) { // use toLowerCase() here if you want
            var actorOscars = actors[i].oscars;
            return actorOscars < myOscars;
        }
    }
    return "Please enter a valid actor name!";
}
```

Comment: You nailed it! I believe that I have a problem understanding the return statement. I thought that I should literally write **return true if ...** or **return false if ..**.
So the first return statement returned back the value after doing the comparison! This is the first time I see this, to be honest. You didn't even have to use the else statement I guess because return stops the execution of the code. The second return statement as if you are saying, if the code up there didn't evaluate, run this. Am I correct?
Thank you very much for this!

Comment: It is just I didn't completely understand how the return statement is returning true/false. What I know is that you have to tell return to do that literally by typing **return true/false if**. I remember that I studied the return statement on MDN website but didn't see such a thing before. Could you please explain? I would appreciate it!

Comment: `actorOscars < myOscars` evaluates to a boolean value that you can return. You can `return` any expression, not a only a literal value. Think of `function sum(a, b) { return (a + b) }` - you can't write out all possible values there. In our case you could equally have written `if (actorOscars < myOscars) return true; else return false;` but it's a waste of bytes :-)

Comment: "*The second return statement as if you are saying, if the code up there didn't evaluate, run this.*" - Exactly. If the loop runs through without matching a name (and `return`ing), the statement after the loop is evaluated.

Comment: "evaluates to a boolean value".. That's the key here. Thank you very much for the explanation and help!

Comment: When voted up, it says that my vote is recorded and it will not change the publicly displayed post score because I have less than 15 reputations. Anyways, I could accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do this with a single `filter` operation as follows;

```js
var hasMoreOscars = (o,a) => a.filter(e => e.oscarCount < o.oscarCount),
              arr = [{a:"leo",oscarCount:1},{a:"me",oscarCount:10},{a:"John", oscarCount: 3}, {a:"she",oscarCount:7}];

console.log(hasMoreOscars(arr[3],arr))
```

Comment: I commented out what "hasMoreOscarsThan" method should have.  I think with your solution, you went far away from the original task I have. I think the solution has to be more simple that the one you gave to me since I am learning Javascript in school and this is my first assignment. The method should only take one parameter which is the actor and compare its oscars with the one who has the method.

Comment: @Adam In my solution you have an array of objects designating actors/actresses (which may have many properties) but we only care about their `oscarCount` property. You pass to the filter an object from the array and it will give you an array of actors/actresses with less `oscarCount` value. Is this not what you were after?

Comment: Yes sir but the way they want me to do it in my assignment is as  **hasMoreOscarsThan: function (){}**. To be honest this is the first time I hear about the **filter operator**. I looked it up and I believe your way it works perfectly but it is not as the way they want me to do it.  It has to return true and false and you console logged it. I tried the loop and it only worked when I use console log but when returning, it returned only the first oscar of the first object. I appreciate your help, Redu. You gave me something new I've never heard of. Thank you.

Comment: @Adam Actually `var hasMoreOscars = (o,a) => a.filter(e => e.oscarCount < o.oscarCount);` is a function but in ES6 syntax. In conventional JS (pre ES6) it would be like `var hasMoreOscars = function(o,a){ return a.filter(e => e.oscarCount < o.oscarCount)};` I would strongly advise you to study ES6 though.

Comment: I will definitely go through and check that out and truly thank you for your great responses. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Bergi Sure I can. The loop was not a good idea because it console logged ALL actors (names and oscars) and returned only the first one. I need to pass one actor as an argument to the method. Here is what I was thinking of at first: 


`hasMoreOscarsThan: function (actorObj){
      var leoName = actors[0].name;
      var leoOscars = actors[0].oscars;
      for (var i = 0; i < actors.length; i++){
        var actorsNames = actors[i].name;
        var actorsOscars = actors[i].oscars;
        console.log(actorsNames);
        console.log(actorsOscars);
      }`